# Adding さん to places

Tags: titles

I have recently come across text which adds さん to places. For example, bookstore is ほんやさん. Is this normal, and in what context?

Comment: I do agree on the duplicate but I might suggest leaving this due to its more straightforward title and searchability.

Comment: Don't worry. The system automatically keeps your question, for exactly the reason you suggest.  It just adds a link to the other question.

Answer (score 1):

ほんやさん usually means "bookstore owner/worker", but CAN mean the store itself.  Adding さん like that to a business name is a common way to refer to such.  ほんや = bookstore, さん referring to the person.

On the other hand, mountains are often referred to, ending in さん, and still refer to the place, eg ふじさん = Mt. Fuji.  However, this is NOT the same さん.  In ほんやさん, the さん is the person-name-honorific さん; in ふじさん, it is 山 with a reading of さん.  These usages are not related.

Edit: Sorry, apparently, with さん it can STILL mean the place.  AFAIK it does more often refer to the person, but you'll have to divine it from context to be sure.

Comment: This is interesting and I did not know this, but is it more common to refer to the shop owner as such or to actually call them a "worker/employee"

Comment: In Japanese, people are usually referred to as their function, like 本屋さん, or even 天気情報のお姉さん (the "sister" presenting the weather forecast).

Comment: Not true.  ほんやさん can still refer to the store.

Comment: Is there something i can read that says more on that? I've never encountered it used like that.

Comment: ^ @C.C. How about: http://okwave.jp/qa/q4990320.html  or for a list of examples: http://oshiete1.nifty.com/qa8651822.html / http://www.rutadeseda.org/kumon-vocabulario.pdf (page 3)